# Cannot parse xml file

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I used to run this file for the last week and it worked out perfect but suddenly today it doesn't work, I haven't changed anything to it.
Can you help me pls?

This is my python code:

```
from lxml import etree
import numpy as np

#Parsing the xml file and creating lists
tree = etree.parse("AnyConv.com__CCSOPM Section 1_Master (1).xml")
root = tree.getroot()
Lista = []
tags = []

#Get the unique tags values
for element in root.iter():
    Lista.append(element.tag)
tags = np.unique(Lista)

#Show the unique tag[attributes] pairs
for tag in tags:
    print(tag,root.xpath(f'//{tag}')[0].attrib.keys())
    
#Changes the tag name to the comply365's tag's name
for p in tree.findall(".//sect1"):
    p.tag = ("section")
for p in tree.findall(".//sect1"):
    p.tag = ("section")
for p in tree.findall(".//informaltable"):
    p.tag = ("table")    
    
#Modify the tag's attributes to its desired form
for cy in root.xpath('//section'):
    cy.attrib['xmlns']='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    cy.attrib['id']='123'
    cy.attrib['type']='policy'
    cy.attrib['xsi']='urn:fontoxml:cpa.xsd:1.0'


for t in root.xpath('//title'):
    t.attrib['id']='123456789'
    
for p in root.xpath('//para'):
    p.attrib['id']='987654321'
    
for p in root.xpath('//table'):
    p.attrib['id']='11111'
    
for ct in root.xpath('//concept'):
    ct.attrib.pop("id", None)

#Print the new xml to make sure it worked:
#print(etree.tostring(root).decode())

    
tree.write("Resultado de tags XML-COMPLY365.xml")
```

this now causes:

```
OSError: Error reading file 'AnyConv.com__CCSOPM Section 1_Master (1).xml': failed to load external entity "AnyConv.com__CCSOPM Section 1_Master (1).xml"
```

If you have any idea how to fix that please feel free to comment down there.

Comment: The error suggests a problem in your XML file. Since you haven't shared that with us, there's very little we can do to help.

Comment: It doesn't matter what file it is, as long as it is an XML file it won't parse it.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists where you think it does? You're trying to read a file named "AnyConv.com__CCSOPM Section 1_Master (1).xml" in your current directory. Maybe you need to provide an explicit path? If you show us the diagnostic steps you've already tried, we can probably provide better help. E.g., create a sample XML file, run an interactive Python session and try to get as far as calling `etree.parse`, and show us the complete transcript.

Comment: Thank you! It turned out that I had duplicated files with the same name in different folders. I was crazy looking for the error everywhere and it turned out to be that. I apologize for such a dumb question and I thank you all for your time!

Comment: Does Comply365 work with Python language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(1)` part in the file name suggests that you already have
`AnyConv.com__CCSOPM Section 1_Master .xml` file in your computer and you
attempted to copy file with this name to your compoter again.

Note also that your file name contains a **space** before `(1)` and this is
strange. This in turn suggests that the name of your "first" file
(without `(1)`) **ends with a space** (and this is **very** strange).

Verify whether your file actually exists.
Or maybe change its name to `AnyConv.com__CCSOPM Section 1_Master.xml`, i.e.:

- without the trailing space,
- without `(1)` at the end.
  Then change the file name accordingly in your code.

Note also that your file name contains a **double** underscore and this also is a weird practice.
Verify whether this underscore in yous file name is **actually** double.

Keeping in your computer many files with the same name (with a "numeric
suffix" in its name) is also a bad practice.
Yet worse practice is to refer to such "duplicated" files in your code.
Change the file name to one without such  "numeric suffix" (in this
case `(1)`) and set the file name in your code as the same.

Yet another hint: Whatever name your file has:

- click on it (once) in the *File Explorer* window,
- press `F2` key, you open edition of this file name, but so far
  the marked text does not include the file name extension (in this case
  ".xml"),
- press `Ctrl-A` to extend the text marking to the **whole** name
  (with the extension).
- press `Ctrl-C` to copy the file name to the clipboard,
- press `Esc` to close edition of the file name,
- open your code editor, place the cursor where your file name is and
  mark the whole file name,
- press `Ctrl-V` to replace it with the clipboard content.

Now in your code you will have the actual file name.

Check also that the directory containing this file is on the list
of directories scanned by Python while attempting to open the file.